# Extracting multiple parts of a .txt file in R some with scientific numbers

Tags: r, readlines

I'm trying to implement a set of calculated xyz shifts to a set of rasters (160 in total). The calculated xyz shifts are reported in a .txt file together with a lot of redundant information (for this operation). The relevant information in the .txt file is stored in multiple lines. I'd like to extract 4 paramters:

- raster name
- x-shift (dx)
- y-shift (dy)
- z-shift (dz)

The raster name is written as part of a longer text string. The calculated x y z shifts are written as scientific numbers, which I'd like to convert to real numbers. I'd like to end up with one file containing the suggested shifts for all 160 raster files.So far my code looks like this, though far from finished

```
shiftfile<- scan("filename.txt", what=list(rastername="",dx=0,dy=0,dz=0)
```

I've looked at `readLines` as well but cannot quite figure out how to implement it for this problem.

Comment: Show us some code that you've attempted.

Comment: Your definition of argument `what` is wrong. It should be a list of types. Try instead `what = list("character", "numeric", "numeric", "numeric")`.